# How to Get unique values based on multiple columns from an array in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have array similar to

```
[{ 's':1,'x': 1,'y':1 }, { 's':2,'x': 1,'y':1 },{ 's':3,'x': 1,'y':2 },{ 's':4,'x': 2,'y':1 },{ 's':5,'x': 2,'y':2 }]
```

In which unique combination of X & Y are required.

Output is :

```
[{ 's':1,'x': 1,'y':1 },{ 's':3,'x': 1,'y':2 },{ 's':4,'x': 2,'y':1 },{ 's':5,'x': 2,'y':2 }]
```

Since X & Y values are same in 1st & 2nd item. 1 has to be removed.

For UniqBy Single column i am using

```
_.uniqBy([{ 's':1,'x': 1,'y':1 }, { 's':2,'x': 1,'y':1 },{ 's':3,'x': 1,'y':2 },{ 's':4,'x': 2,'y':1 },{ 's':5,'x': 2,'y':2 }], 'y');
```

But i need for the Combination Of 2 or more keys.

```
_.uniqBy([{ 's':1,'x': 1,'y':1 }, { 's':2,'x': 1,'y':1 },{ 's':3,'x': 1,'y':2 },{ 's':4,'x': 2,'y':1 },{ 's':5,'x': 2,'y':2 }], '[x]','[y]');
```

and many. None of them worked/

```
[{ 's':1,'x': 1,'y':1 }, { 's':2,'x': 1,'y':1 },{ 's':3,'x': 1,'y':2 },{ 's':4,'x': 2,'y':1 },{ 's':5,'x': 2,'y

_.uniqBy([{ 's':1,'x': 1,'y':1 }, { 's':2,'x': 1,'y':1 },{ 's':3,'x': 1,'y':2 },{ 's':4,'x': 2,'y':1 },{ 's':5,'x': 2,'y':2 }], 'y');



[{ 's':1,'x': 1,'y':1 },{ 's':3,'x': 1,'y':2 },{ 's':4,'x': 2,'y':1 },{ 's':5,'x': 2,'y':2 }]
```

Comment: I tweaked the tags since this does not appear to be an Angular related question, but rather one about lodash's `uniqBy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` and `findIndex` for an extremely simple vanilla JavaScript solution (everything done in Lodash can be done in JavaScript, Lodash just simplifies things):

```js
const arr = [{'s':1,'x':1,'y':1},{'s':2,'x':1,'y':1},{'s':3,'x':1,'y':2},{'s':4,'x':2,'y':1},{'s':5,'x':2,'y':2}];

const res = arr.findIndex(({ x, y }, i, a) => i == a.findIndex(e => e.x == x && e.y == y));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

---

Lodash solutions:

Using [`_.uniqBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#uniqBy) comparing the two fields as a comma-separated string of values:

```js
const arr = [{'s':1,'x':1,'y':1},{'s':2,'x':1,'y':1},{'s':3,'x':1,'y':2},{'s':4,'x':2,'y':1},{'s':5,'x':2,'y':2}];

const res = _.uniqBy(arr, ({ x, y }) => `${x}${y}`);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Using [`_.uniqWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#uniqWith):

```js
const arr = [{'s':1,'x':1,'y':1},{'s':2,'x':1,'y':1},{'s':3,'x':1,'y':2},{'s':4,'x':2,'y':1},{'s':5,'x':2,'y':2}];

const res = _.uniqWith(arr, ({ x, y }, { x: x1, y: y1 }) => x == x1 && y == y1);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just want to know why  i am getting error **Property 'x' does not exist on type 'String'.**  with **_.uniqBy**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function and concatenate the numbers.

```js
console.log(_.uniqBy([
   { 's':1,'x': 1,'y':1 },
   { 's':2,'x': 1,'y':1 },
   { 's':3,'x': 1,'y':2 },
   { 's':4,'x': 2,'y':1 },
   { 's':5,'x': 2,'y':2 }
], el => `${el.x}${el.y}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.14/lodash.min.js"></script>
```